# ImportError: No module named 'rasterio.vrt'

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, geotiff, rasterio

I am using an example code for NDVI computation from `Dask`. The link to the code is as follows. 
[code for computing NDVI](https://examples.dask.org/applications/satellite-imagery-geotiff.html)

while creating xarray datasets using the below block of code,

```
import xarray as xr
red = xr.open_rasterio('red.tif', chunks={'band': 1, 'x': 1024, 'y': 1024})
nir = xr.open_rasterio('nir.tif', chunks={'band': 1, 'x': 1024, 'y': 1024})
nir
```

I am getting the following **import error**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-a3df5765cb4e> in <module>
  1 import xarray as xr
----> 2 red = xr.open_rasterio('red.tif', chunks={'band': 1, 'x': 1024, 'y': 1024})
  3 nir = xr.open_rasterio('nir.tif', chunks={'band': 1, 'x': 1024, 'y': 1024})
  4 nir
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xarray/backends/rasterio_.py in open_rasterio(filename, parse_coordinates, chunks, cache, lock)
213     """
214     import rasterio
--> 215     from rasterio.vrt import WarpedVRT
216     vrt_params = None
217     if isinstance(filename, rasterio.io.DatasetReader):
ImportError: No module named 'rasterio.vrt'
```

I have searched to my best and couldnot find help. It would be great if anyone can help me to identify the cause of this import error.

Comment: Please specify how you installed xarray and rasterio, and the versions you now appear to have.

Comment: In case this is casued by an old rasterio installation, here is a general howto on installing Python with all the neccessary geospatial libraries. https://medium.com/@chrieke/howto-install-python-for-geospatial-applications-1dbc82433c05

Comment: I used pip3 install xarray and it got installed. But when I installed rasterio using pip3 it did not work. so I used sudo apt--get install rasterio. The version of rasterio I got is 0.36.0-1and xarray is 0.12.1. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @ChristophRieke I installed all the package you suggested but still no luck. Any other suggestion please.

Comment: @parupalu  The old 0.36 version is the default version using the anaconda channel. Try conda install -c conda-forge rasterio=1.0.22, if that doesn't solve it try the tutorial step for step.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the conda package manager, which can handle both Python packages like Xarray as well as binary packages like GDAL and rasterio in a consistent manner.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. But it dinot work. It still shows the same error. I did the following: Installed conda package and then installed gdal, rasterio and xarray with conda. Can you suggest anything more?

Answer (score 0):

When I get that error, it's usually when package dependancies get out of sync.   A `conda update --all` fixes it for me.